How to propogate alarms up customer hierarchy
I am trying to set up alarms in our cloud professional edition of ThingsBoard.
Under our tenant user, we have a number of customers, and they in turn have customers, all set up in the customer hierarchy. I think I've got this right.
Alarms are then set up in the Alarm Rules of Device Profiles. I've not got any of the 'Propogate alarm...' tick boxes ticked (although doing this didn't seem to make a difference.
In the Rule Chain root rule, I've added a link to a separate Alarms rule. .
In the Alarms rule  I first change the originator to the owner of the device, then look for related customers to get those higher up the hierarchy - . I then (i) send emails, (ii) send notifications.
I've had to add relations between customers for this to work also, mirroring the hierarchy.
It is mostly working as I'd like, but I've got a couple of problems:

The notifications only appear for the customer at the top of the hierarchy.
The customer at the bottom of the hierachy (with the devices assigned directly to them) can see the Alarms in the Alarms page OK. The customer higher up the hierarchy **can **see the alarms on an alarms widget on a dashboard, but they don't show up on the Alarms page (and the alarms count widget shows 0 total as well).

Ideally I just want the following:

For alarms to be visible for the direct customer who owns the devices
For these alarms to also be visible to the owner of this customer, and so on up the chain (ideally with the option to notify of the alarms of sub-customers as a configurable option per sub-customer)
For alarms to be matched on all of the following (i) Alarms page, (ii) Alarms widgets (and counts), (iii) Notifications, (iv) Emails
For users of each customer to be able to opt in/out of emails.

I think I've probably made it more complicated than it needs to be. Any advice would be appreciated.
Many thanks,
Steve
